# Delete all non-numeric symbols, add "-" and move values under certain criteria in R

Tags: r

I have the sample dataset below in which I want:
1) Delete all non-numeric symboles like letters, parentheses etc.
2) If one columns has more than one phones (up to 4) every phone number should be moved to a new column.
3) All phones should be transformed into the form : 999-999-9999

```
dt<-data.frame(phone1<-c("B: 2125281108 L: 6315378589","B: 6312047931","B: 646 471 7491","H: ( 212) 2066001 B: 2127665050","H: ( 5165264459","H: 845 735 6340 B: 212 752 6164 L: 631 537 6333 Cell 1: 845 596 6036","H: 9195333092 L: 6312670794 Cell 1: 5188211814","H: 7188366395 B: 7188364600 x1115 L: 6312834294 house # tenant","H: 6315372000 (L allyHamp Country) B: 6315372000 (L ally #) L: 6315375012"))
colnames(dt)<-c("phone1")
```

I would use `gsub()` but the original dataset is too big so I would like a generic solution that would keep only numbers (phone-numbers) and then achieve requirements 2 and 3. I work in excel but I would like to know if there is a way to automatically achieve this through R.

For example this code chunk `gsub("("," ", dt$phone1)`would replace all "(" with " " but since there are different kinds non-numeric symbols and letters in the column I want a solution in which I will not have to replace every specific symbol but just to keep the numbers.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that the data set is "too big" to use `gsub`. and using `gsub` is probably one of the more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried with `gsub`

Comment: However, if it really is a performance issue, `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex` may be faster

Comment: I added an example. My issue is that since the dataset is large I do not know what kind of non-numeric symbols may exist so I do not want to replace them with " " but I want just to keep the numbers.

Comment: As a side note, don't use `<-` inside `data.frame()`, just `data.frame(phone1=...)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll split into the second column if we have a second phone number based on a colon with a letter prefix appearing somewhere other than the start of the string

```
library(stringr)

# positive lookahead looks for a letter then :
# [^^] means not at the start of the string (it seems, although check the comments, someone may explain why this works, but doesn't do what I think it does)
df2 <- str_split_fixed(dt$phone1, "[^^](?=[[:alpha:]]:)",2)

     [,1]                [,2]           
[1,] "B: 2125281108"     "L: 6315378589"
[2,] "B: 6312047931"     ""             
[3,] "B: 646 471 7491"   ""             
[4,] "H: ( 212) 2066001" "B: 2127665050"
[5,] "H: ( 5165264459"   ""
```

Remove all non-numeric characters

```
df2 <- apply(df2, 2,str_replace_all, "[^\\d]", "")

[,1]         [,2]        
[1,] "2125281108" "6315378589"
[2,] "6312047931" ""          
[3,] "6464717491" ""          
[4,] "2122066001" "2127665050"
[5,] "5165264459" ""
```

Then finally insert the dashes:

```
as.data.frame(apply(df2, 2, FUN = function(x) gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})$", "\\1-\\2-\\3", x)))

            V1           V2
1 212-528-1108 631-537-8589
2 631-204-7931             
3 646-471-7491             
4 212-206-6001 212-766-5050
5 516-526-4459
```

If you have area codes in some numbers, you'll have to first check the length of the number and then format accordingly.

Comment: Also, can someone explain why `[^^]` works? A quick consult of Regex documentation suggests that `[^^]` asserts that the engine *cannot* match a literal `^`, and yet the split doesn't work without `[^^]`.

Comment: Or because we're in multi-line mode, does this mean that a literal `^` is still asserting the beginning of the string, rather than the literal character itself?

Comment: your solution nearly works but I just updated the Q with a scenario of 4 phone numbers instead of 2 and it does not.

Comment: The third argument of `str_split_fixed` specifies how many columns to split into. In this case, I used `2` for your initial example, however, you could replace it with `4`, or another number of your choosing

Comment: Also, your updated example breaks the rule of each phone number being proceeded by a colon `:`, so we'd have to adjust the split criteria slightly as well.

Comment: And you could modify your split pattern to something like `df2 <- str_split_fixed(dt$phone1, "[^^](?=([[:alpha:]]:)|(\\d:))",4)` to catch cases where you have a digit instead of a letter with the colon. I'm not going to try to catch every edge case for you, but this is the general process. Sometimes it's easier to use two separate patterns than it is to write a single regex pattern that catches everything. One thing I haven't addressed is how to handle extensions.

Comment: Also, to clarify my initial comment response, the new example breaks the rule of every phone number being preceded by a letter, then a colon.

Comment: And of course with numbers than are longer or shorter than 10 digits, you'll have to specify a different rule for how to format them.